# Profile of a human foot

Tags: human-anatomy

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, so please let me know in case it is not. My question is just out of curiosity.

**What is the reason for curved human foot profile?**

First a bit of clarification in layman terms. When looking at a human foot sideways on the inside, you see an arch along the foot length, however there is no such arch when looking from the other side (imagine a footprint and how it has a curve on the inside and is flat on other side).

I looked on Google to find the answer. Pardon my lack in knowledge of biology vernacular/terminologies. Reading through wiki article on [Arches of the foot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arches_of_the_foot), they do describe the two arches - longitudinal arch and transverse arch. In the laymen explanation I gave earlier, if I understand the anatomy right, the transverse arch is what leads to the footprint shaped that way. As I understand, they explain how the arches are responsible for the stiffness of the foot, akin to how arches of a building help support more weight will lower deflection compared to other configurations. Also the space under the dome enable the elastic soft tissue to spread and provide enough contact surface for the body weight to be effectively distributed. On transverse arch, they say it creates a half dome and the two foot together form the complete dome. However, structurally, they will not fulfill the same role as a full dome, far from it in my humble opinion. **Can someone explain the structural benefit of the half dome of the transverse arch?**